# File share from a windows 8 to windows 7

Tags: networking

I have a new computer that runs windows 8 and another computer that runs windows 7 home premium. I need to be able to share files between the two computers. How can I network these two computers together?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the "share with" option on Windows7.
More informations on the Microsoft website: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-essentials#1TC=windows-7